# Trying to create fields based on a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, aggregate-functions

I'm having some trouble with the query below. I am trying to determine if the "category" field is A, B or C and then creating a field based on the category. That field would sum up payments field. But I'm running into error saying "incorrect syntax near keyword As". I am creating this in a SQL View. Using SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT r.id, r.category
CASE 
WHEN r.category = 'A' then SUM(r.payment) As A_payments 
WHEN r.category = 'B' then SUM(r.payment) As B_payments
WHEN r.category = 'C' then SUM(r.payment) As C_payments
END
FROM r_invoiceTable As r
GROUP BY r.id, r.category
```

I have data where all of the above cases should be executed because the data that I have has A,B and C

Sample Data- r_invoiceTable

```
Id --- Category ---- Payment
222      A      ----   50
444      A      ----   30
111      B      ----   90
777      C      ----   20
555      C      ----   40
```

Desired Output
A_payments = 80, B_payments = 90, C_payments = 60

Comment: Yes, but I want to have 3 separate fields...I can't have only one field. I need 3 separate fields to be created with the sum of the payment based on the category.

Comment: When you say you have data that has all three A, B and C, do you mean the same row has all 3 categories? If thats the case, then I think only 1 of the cases would be executed. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: for every category you are computing same `SUM`; what's the point of using `CASE`?

Comment: @mshsayem well every category would have a different sum. that's why i need to separate it by categories

Comment: What is the _Sample Data_? your desired output, or `r_invoiceTable` table data? Do you want category-wise payment sum?

Comment: it is the r_invoiceTable

Comment: @mshsayem: Yes, the first paragraph's last sentence says so. (I missed that too when first read the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'A' THEN payment END) AS A_payments,
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'B' THEN payment END) AS B_payments,
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'C' THEN payment END) AS C_payments
FROM r_invoiceTable
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you want this (category-wise payment sum)?:

```
SELECT r.category, SUM(r.payment) As Payments 
FROM r_invoiceTable As r
GROUP BY r.category
```

Output will be like:

```
category     Payments
---------   ------------
    A          80
    B          90 
    C          60
```

If you like these numbers in a single row here is a naive approach:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT SUM(r.payment) From r_invoiceTable As r Where r.category = 'A') as A_Payment,
   (SELECT SUM(r.payment) From r_invoiceTable As r Where r.category = 'B') as B_Payment,
   (SELECT SUM(r.payment) From r_invoiceTable As r Where r.category = 'C') as C_Payment
```

Comment: Well, will the above solution provide me with 3 separate columns? Because in my web application I have to place 3 separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.r_invoiceTable
PIVOT
( SUM(payment)
FOR category IN ([a],[b],[c])
) AS pivoted
```

Comment: You'd have to limit the columns in the source to just `payment` and `category`. Otherwise `id` and other columns, if any, would also take part in grouping. I.e. instead of `FROM dbo.r_invoiceTable` you'd need to select `FROM (SELECT payment, category FROM dbo.r_invoiceTable) alias`.